# Use of finally in java

Tags: java, try-catch, finally

Consider the code

```
try{
    //code
} catch(Exception e) {
    // handle
} finally {
    // close open connections
}
```

and this

```
try{
    //code
} catch(Exception e) {
    // handle
}
// close open connections
```

since both are same what is the necessity of finally block?

Comment: Obviously, both are not the same: The `finally` block always executes when the `try` block exits. This ensures that the `finally` block is executed even if an unexpected exception occurs.

Comment: As general rule, you should avoid "catch all" style blocks

Comment: Exception can happen in catch block

Comment: If an exception occurs, you're second snippet won't reach the close statements, while in the first one, the finally clause will be reached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `finally` block will always be executed, even if you don't catch all the exceptions thrown by the `try` block in the `catch` block, or if the `catch` block throws a new exception.

In the second snippet, the code following the `try`-`catch` block won't be executed if either the `try` or `catch` blocks throw exceptions not caught by the `catch` block.

Answer (score 2):

A `finally` block is much safer, as it's guaranteed to execute even if your `try` block throws an exception that isn't handled by the `catch` block or `return`s.

It also has the side effect of organizing all the "cleanup" code in an expected location, making the code (arguably) easier to maintain.

It's worth noting, by the way, that if you're using Java 7 or higher, and the resource you're handling is an [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) (such as a [`java.sql.Connection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html), for example), there's an even cleaner solution - the [try-with-resource syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/89/exceptions-and-exception-handling/1581/the-try-with-resources-statement#t=201706060539441230227), which saves you the hassle of explicitly closing the resource:

```
try (Connection con = /* something */) {
    // code
} catch (SomeException e) {
    // handle
    // If there's nothing intelligent to do, this entire clause can be omitted.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

finally block is used to execute important code such as closing connection, stream etc. finally block in java can be used to put "cleanup" code such as closing a file, closing connection etc.

Java finally block is always executed whether exception is handled or not.

For each try block there can be zero or more catch blocks, but only one finally block.
The finally block will not be executed if program exits(either by calling System.exit() or by causing a fatal error that causes the process to abort).